# How to save image after animation?

Tags: android, imageview

*This question was modified according to progress, for future use*

I have an image in an `ImageView`. There's a **rotate** button near it. This is what it does:

```
imageView.animate().rotation(imageView.getRotation()+45);
```

And then I save the image after the changes:

```
Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

But when I extract the image after the changes, the old image shows up (unrotated):

```
rotatedImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

How do I get the new image as a `Bitmap` after the animation?

**EDIT:**

Following @Droid Chris's answer, this is what I'm getting:

*I set the background to black so you understand better. Eventually it'll be transparent*

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

**OBSERVATION:**

@Droid Chris's answer works when I rotate the image by multiples of 90. But multiples of 45 for instance are problematic...

I do need it to be 45 though

**SOLUTION:**

So I used @Droid Chris's function, but somehow it was downsampling my image. So I needed to set `android:scaleType="center"` in the xml for the `ImageView`. That solved the downsampling.

Also, to keep the transition animation, I had to do:

```
imageView.animate().rotation(imageView.getRotation()+45);
```

on every rotation operation, and the following only once when I want to save it:

```
Bitmap oldBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().copy(((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().getConfig(), true);

Bitmap bitmapAfterRotation = getRotatedBitmap(oldBitmap,imageView.getRotation());
```

Also, in `getRotatedBitmap()`, I wrote `mat.setRotate(angle);` and not `mat.postRotate(angle);`

Now it works as expected.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a matrix to the image like so taking into account the angle that you rotated while getting width and height this way:

```
((BitmapDrawable)mUserProfileImageView.getDrawable()).getBounds().height()
or
((BitmapDrawable)mUserProfileImageView.getDrawable()).getBounds().width()

private Bitmap getRotatedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int angle, int width, int height) {
    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
    mat.postRotate(angle);

    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, mat, true);

    bm.recycle();

    return newBitmap;
}
```

Comment: This somehow also resizes the image (It smalls it down). For some reason `Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight(), mat, true);` returns `mWidth` and `mHeight` both equal **-1** (negative 1)

Comment: where do you set the bitmap for the image view?

Comment: I think the problem is those `(0,0)` you're setting in `createBitmap()`. The image is a circular `png` with a transparent background. Maybe that's why

Comment: OK! Get this: If I rotate it in 90 degrees, it works! But 45 is problematic. I do need it to be 45 though. Any ideas?

Comment: OK solution found. I shoulda set `android:scaleType="center"` in the xml